# Using a variable in replacing a substring in another variable in a loop in Windows batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The following code is assumed to replace the *col3* substring in the variable *dir* with the value of the variable *var* in every iteration, but it fails to do so. Does anyone know what is wrong with this code?

code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET dir=col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
SET var=v%%i
SET dir=!dir:col3=%var%!
ECHO !dir!
)
PAUSE
```

output:

```
col1 col2  col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
col1 col2  col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
col1 col2  col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
col1 col2  col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
col1 col2  col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

desired output:

```
col1 col2 v1 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
col1 col2 v2 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
col1 col2 v3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
col1 col2 v4 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
col1 col2 v5 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

Comment: you need double delayed expansion: `for %%V in (!var!) do SET "dir=!dir:col3=%%V!"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after hours of searching for this problem, I found out that changing the line

```
SET dir=!dir:col3=%var%!
```

to

```
SET dir=%dir:col3=!var!%
```

solved the issue.

Comment: No, this is simply wrong, you need to delay expansion since you are in a loop, and you must expand the inner variable (`var`) before the outer one (`dir`)! A possible way is: `call set "dir=%%dir:col3=!var!%%"`

Comment: Sorry, I have to withdraw my previous comment, since in your particular situation your answer actually does provide the solution (accidentally?), because: For every loop iteration, `dir` is expanded to its *original* value due to immediate (`%`-)expansion, with `col3` replaced by the *literal* string `!var!`; delayed expansion then does the rest and expands `!var!` by its current value…

Comment: My code suggestion however correctly replaces `col3` with `v1` in the *first* loop iteration; but for every *further* iteration, `dir` expandes to its *modified* value due to delayed expansion, so there is no more `col3` in the string, hence the same value as for the first iteration becomes returned again. Sorry for drawing a hasty and mistaken conclusion!